# How do I not repeat myself when writing sql queries?

Tags: sql, .net

Lets take this simple query (code below may not be exact)

```
select a, b, c from inventory where x=:x AND y=:y limit 20
```

Lets say I use using an ORM that maps the rows to an inventory class and my function was this

```
inventory[] get_inventory(int x, int y)
```

Now lets say I need extra data using the SAME query. I want to join a table and get 2 extra fields on top of that query

```
class inventory2 : inventory { string owner_name; long owner_id; }
...
inventory2[] get_inventory2(int x, int y) {
...
select a, b, c, o.owner_name, o.id as owner_id from inventory i join owner o on i.owner=o.id where x=:x AND y=:y limit 20
CHANGES         ^----------------------------^                  ^--------------------------^
```

This should be the same query in every way. I ONLY want extra fields. I can't think of a way to do this except copy/pasting sql and hope I don't forget to change one when I change the other.

How do I not repeat myself?

Comment: These two queries are not even close to being the same. The first query pulls data from a single table. The second query as it is written performs a double outer (or cartesian) join on two tables. Even though you have added the match criteria for the join, you are missing the syntax necessary to keep it from being an inner join. The inner join will get you closer to what you are talking about.

Comment: I thought that was an inner join. How would you suggest rewriting this? (Even if it's impossible to not repeat myself in sql)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to share the select list since this is two distinct queries, and both need their own list of fields to select.

Comment: What do you do when you have something like `SELECT a.c1, a.c2, b.c1, b.c2 FROM aTable AS a INNER JOIN bTable AS b ON a.id = b.id`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using an ORM tool that generates the select queries for you, then don't try to over-reduce duplication.

It is possible to do it by separating the queries into fragments and then based on flags you add the fragments you need, like:

```
var sql = "SELECT A, B, C";

if (test1) sql += ", D, E, F";
if (test2) sql += ", G, H, I";

sql += " FROM inventory ";

if (test1) sql += "inner join .. ";
if (test2) sql += "inner join .. ";
```

This does work and in some cases (particularly reporting with very dynamic filters) I've done this myself, but it's usually far better to lie with the duplication and have separate queries that are readable then a mess of conditions making it unmaintainable, harder to test, and easily able to generate bad queries depending on combinations of conditions.

One of our developers did an experiment with a SQL pre-parser to embed conditions.  We had SQL like this:

```
SELECT
    a, b, c
    , d, e, f   /*? test1 */
    , g, h, i   /*? test2 */
FROM
    Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.FKID    /*? test1 */
        INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.FKID    /*? test */
```

This is better than traditional dynamic SQL, it's more readable, but it's still not great and can still be easily messed up and product bad queries depending on combinations of conditions.  We ended up not using this in production at all.

All that said, a good ORM is also a good way to go.  :-)

Comment: Do you recommend any? I'm using dapper.net which is great but that's a light ORM meant to convert rows to objects (quickly). It doesn't do anything with sql generation. Also I cant exactly do this unless I do it at the namespace level. I'm returning two different classes. I guess I can return the derived class in both instances but I rather not if I need not

Comment: I agree. Setting aside an ORM that eliminates the need for this altogether, dynamic SQL came to my mind too...but landed on exactly the same thought regarding maintainability compromised by complexity versus a bit of duplication that at least has the benefit of being more readable. I further agree that reporting/search queries with very dynamic filters are an exception to this rule.

Comment: @acidzombie24, I personally like Dapper.net as well for raw performance. In our application we use something similar that was developed in-house a long time ago, except we generate all the classes and converters at compile-time so we don't even have that initial overhead (and we know our DB can not change without a code change anyways). If you want a full-featured ORM, then go with nHibernate. It'll give you more features, but is not as performant. For most applications, it wouldn't matter--the ORM is very very rarely a bottleneck. Dapper.net was made for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @acidzombie24, regarding the classes issue, you can do that by having different public methods with specific return types and a private method with the actual implementation that returns a parent type. Then in the specific types you know you can safely cast to the more-specific child type and return that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your query to use an INNER JOIN or your query (as written) will get a [Cartesian join resultset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

```
SELECT a, b, c, o.owner_name, o.id as owner_id 
FROM inventory i INNER JOIN owner o ON i.owner=o.id 
WHERE x=:x AND y=:y LIMIT 20
```

If this is for SQL Server you will also need to remove the `LIMIT 20` and put `TOP 20` in the selection list.

```
SELECT TOP 20 a, b, c, o.owner_name, o.id as owner_id 
...
```

Comment: Without stating inner it is a cross join? I think I have been writing bad queries if sqlite is the exception. Sqlite says `Side note: Special handling of CROSS JOIN. There is no difference between the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," join operators. They are completely interchangeable in SQLite. The "CROSS JOIN" join operator produces the same result as the "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," operators, but is handled differently by the query optimizer in that it prevents the query optimizer from reordering the tables in the join` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: That definition is nowhere close to what the ANSI standard is for CROSS JOINS.